# ORACLE insertion from other table using TOAD does not align properly (Showing NULL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created new table name NEW_TABLE like

```
Create table NEW_TABLE 
(
    Col_1 VARCHAR(50), 
    Col_2_ VARCHAR(50),
    Col_3_ VARCHAR(50)
)
```

I am inserting value from OLD_TABLE like this way

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE (Col_1)  
    SELECT Col_1
    FROM OLD_TABLE_A 
    WHERE Col_1 IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE (Col_2)  
    SELECT Col_1 
    FROM OLD_TABLE_B 
    WHERE Col_1 IS NOT NULL;
```

When I want to see the NEW_TABLE it show the data like this

```
Col_1    Col_2   
-----    -----
AA
BB
CC
         XX
         MM
         ZZ
         PP
         CC
```

I am getting NULL value at the start of Col_2.

I want this:

```
 Col_1    Col_2
 -----    -----
    AA       XX
    BB       MM
    CC       ZZ
             PP
             CC
```

I have to insert different column in different time separately.while inserting a column I do not want to consider other

Comment: How many rows do you want to have in NEW_TABLE? You are inserting 6 rows, so you get 6 rows in result; you have to decide if you want to insert 3 rows or insert 6 and have a query showing 3 aggregated rows. Once you have decided this, it will be possible help you to find a proper solution

Comment: What is the rule to map value `AA` from `table_A` with value `XX` from `table_B`? Take this rule and join the tables.

Comment: I used those query for example, there is no relation between Col_1 and Col_2. I just want use them to store my values but the problem occurred when i want to insert in Col_2. It's always starting after Col_1 and giving NULL on the top

Comment: How will you know which values to match up? Why does AA correspond with XX and so on?

Comment: The best thing would be to use two different tables instead of one table with two completely independent columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create table NEW_TABLE 
(
    Col_1 VARCHAR(5), 
    Col_2_ VARCHAR(5),
    Col_3_ VARCHAR(5)
);


Create table OLD_TABLE 
(
    Col_1 VARCHAR(5), 
    Col_2_ VARCHAR(5),
    Col_3_ VARCHAR(5)
);

insert into old_table values ('AA','XX', null);
insert into old_table values ('BB','MM', null);
insert into old_table values ('CC','ZZ', null);
insert into old_table values (null,'PP', 'YYY');
insert into old_table values (null,'CC', 'XXX');


select * from old_table;

COL_1 COL_2 COL_3

----- ----- -----
AA    XX         
BB    MM         
CC    ZZ         
      PP    YYY  
      CC    XXX  

alter table new_table add (position number);
```

.

```
MERGE INTO new_table D
   USING  (select rownum position, old_table.* from old_table where col_1 is not null) S
   ON (d.position = s.position)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.Col_1 = S.Col_1
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (d.position, D.Col_1)
     VALUES (s.position, S.Col_1);  

MERGE INTO new_table D
   USING  (select rownum position, old_table.* from old_table where col_2_ is not null) S
   ON (d.position = s.position)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.Col_2_ = S.Col_2_
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (d.position, D.Col_2_)
     VALUES (s.position,S.Col_2_);  

MERGE INTO new_table D
   USING  (select rownum position, old_table.* from old_table where col_3_ is not null) S
   ON (d.position = s.position)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.Col_3_ = S.Col_3_
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (d.position, D.Col_3_)
     VALUES (s.position, S.Col_3_);

select * from new_table order by position; 

COL_1 COL_2 COL_3   POSITION
----- ----- ----- ----------
AA    XX    YYY            1
BB    MM    XXX            2
CC    ZZ                   3
      PP                   4
      CC                   5
```

You can drop POSITION column from new_table after the operation if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

Since you stated in a comment that there is no relation between the columns, and that there are the same number of columns in old_table_a and old_table_b this will work.  I broke it into steps to make following it easier.

First establish the original table with a WITH clause.  Then with another WITH clause, add an ID column which is the row number.  Finally SELECT, joining on the ID (uncomment the INSERT line at the top when you are satisfied with the results).

Note the "ID" is meaningless as a true ID and serves only to match rows one for one in each table.  If these tables have different numbers of rows you will get unexpected results but it meets your requirements.

```
SQL> --insert into new_table(col_1, col_2)
SQL> -- Set up the original old table A
SQL> with old_table_a(col_1) as (
     select 'AA' from dual union
     select 'BB' from dual union
     select 'CC' from dual
   ),
   -- Add the id, which is the row_number
   ota_rn(id, col_1) as (
     select row_number() over (order by col_1) as id, col_1
     from old_table_a
   ),
   -- Set up the original old table B
   old_table_b(col_1) as (
     select 'XX' from dual union
     select 'YY' from dual union
     select 'ZZ' from dual
   ),
   -- Add the id, which is the row_number
   otb_rn(id, col_1) as (
     select row_number() over (order by col_1) as id, col_1
     from old_table_b
   )
   -- Now join on the ID (which is really meaningless)
   select a.col_1, b.col_1
   from   ota_rn a
          join otb_rn b
            on (a.id = b.id);

COL_1      COL_1
---------- ----------
AA         XX
BB         YY
CC         ZZ

SQL>
```

Update before I even post the answer: I see from subsequent comments as I was about to post that you want to allow for adding additional columns with perhaps differing numbers of rows, etc.  That will call for UPDATING, not INSERTING and unless you use the fake row_number ID method I use above really makes no sense in a true relational table. In that case this answer will not meet your needs but I will leave it here in case you want to adapt it for your needs.

I suggest you reconsider your approach to your original problem as this path will take you down a dark hole.  You will have unrelated attributes in a table which violates basic database design and makes selecting this data in the future problematic at best (how will you query results? I'm curious how you will use this table).  Maybe you should take a step back and reconsider your approach and at least start with some properly normalized tables.  What's the real issue your are trying to solve?  I bet there is a better way.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer ....is their any trick to just store the data side by side in a same table without having any connection between them ??  (different column has different row length).. ??

Comment: There's no trick, you can do it.  The problem will be in selecting that data.  How are you going to use it?  What will the criteria be to select it?  As it stands now you have no primary key that uniquely identifies a row in the table (an instance of an entity).  If you are just selecting all of col_2 for example, then it really is it's own table in a column.  We need more info on the big picture to answer how to design the tables.  That's really another question under the database_normalization tag.

Comment: @Gary_W, you're losing records.Change the query to use FULL JOIN

Comment: No, that's what I want, a 1 to 1 correlation by the row number.  There's no relationship between the rows in each table besides by the row number. The other answers give Cartesian products which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @Gary_W, add `union all select 'DD' from dual` to your demo.P.s. Are you aware to the difference between UNION and UNION ALL?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz You may not be aware of the edits to the OP. At the time I answered this the OP was looking for a 1 to 1 between 2 tables. The requirements have now changed as new questions have been asked in comments and edits have been made to the OP.  Your answer handles the latest iteration so I'm getting off the bus here before it changes again.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

`insert` creates new row. If you want to fill `column2` values where `column1` is already filled you need to use `update` or `merge`. But as mentioned in comments you need to know how to match `column2` with `column1`. You haven't provided any join condition for the data so people are guessing what you need. Please post some sample data from `tableA` and `tableB` and how it should look in `new_table`.

I think you need something like:

step1:

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE (Col_1)  
    SELECT Col_1
    FROM OLD_TABLE_A 
    WHERE Col_1 IS NOT NULL;
```

step2:

```
merge into NEW_TABLE n
using OLD_TABLE_B b
on (/*HERE PUT JOIN CONDITION*/)
when matched then update set n.col_2_ = b.col_1;
```

step3:

```
merge into NEW_TABLE n
using OLD_TABLE_C c
on (/*HERE PUT JOIN CONDITION*/)
when matched then update set n.col_3_ = c.col_1;
```

Answer (score 2):

The second INSERT should be UPDATE, something like:

```
UPDATE NEW_TABLE
   SET Col_2 = (SELECT Col_2
                  FROM OLD_TABLE
                 WHERE Col_1 = <selection value>
               )
 WHERE Col_1 = <selection value> ;
```

Comment: Could you pleas describe `Col_1 = <selection value> `, i have million data in Col_1, and while inserting Col_2 i do not want to consider Col_1. Another thing need to mention that bot Col_1 and Col_2 have same number of  rows. Col_2 is bigger than Col_1 and how about inserting NEW_TABLE from different OLD_Tables

Comment: Well, your words _I have to insert different column in different time separately_ made me think that adding the value for `Col_2` takes place asynchronously and one record at the time. If that is not the case, please explain what the nature of the second process is.

Comment: while inserting a column i do not want to consider other. I need to start from first row while preserving other value of other column

Comment: @RaihanUddinAhmed There's no such thing as a *first row* in SQL.

Comment: @shawnt00 of-course i know that, but i just want to know is their any trick to just store the data side by side in a same table without having any connection between them ?? , that's all

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer is that you should

```
insert into NEW_TABLE (Col_1, Col_2)
    select OLD_TABLE_A.Col_1, OLD_TABLE_B.Col_2
        from OLD_TABLE_A, OLD_TABLE_B
        where OLD_TABLE_A.Col_1 is not null
            and OLD_TABLE_B.Col_2 is not null;
```

the problem is that you will then get

```
Col_1 Col_2
----- -----
AA    XX
AA    YY
AA    ZZ
BB    XX
BB    YY
BB    ZZ
CC    XX
CC    YY
CC    ZZ
```

now the question you need to answer (that's what Dimitry asked in his comment) is how do you decide that you do *not* want the `AA,YY`, `AA,ZZ`, `BB,XX`, `BB,ZZ`, `CC,XX` and `CC,YY` ? Once you have an answer to this you can augment the `where` condition to remove them.

Comment: i don't want to insert col1 and col2 at the same time ... i know that your answer will work , but in future if i want to insert into Col3 it will again give  Null first and then it will start insert where col1 and col2 has ended.... what will happen if Col3 has more rows than Col1 and Col2.... how can i insert them starting from 1st position

Comment: The idea of ‘position’ is kind of anti SQL.
Maybe you should present the real case you are facing.

Answer (score 2):

```
select      min (case tab when 'A' then Col_1 end)  as Col_1
           ,min (case tab when 'B' then Col_1 end)  as Col_2

from        (           SELECT 'A' as tab ,rownum as rn ,Col_1 FROM OLD_TABLE_A 
            union all   SELECT 'B'        ,rownum       ,Col_1 FROM OLD_TABLE_B
            )

group by    rn 

order by    rn
;
```

#### OR

```
select      min (Col_1)  as Col_1
           ,min (Col_2)  as Col_2

from        (           SELECT 'A' as tab,rownum as rn,Col_1 ,null  as Col_2 FROM OLD_TABLE_A 
            union all   SELECT 'B'       ,rownum      ,null  ,Col_1          FROM OLD_TABLE_B
            )

group by    rn 

order by    rn
;
```

#### OR

```
select      a.Col_1     
           ,b.Col_1     as Col_2

from                    (SELECT rownum as rn,Col_1 FROM OLD_TABLE_A) a
            full join   (SELECT rownum as rn,Col_1 FROM OLD_TABLE_B) b
            on          b.rn = a.rn

order by    coalesce (a.rn,b.rn)
;
```

---

#### Results

```
+-------+-------+
| COL_1 | COL_2 |
+-------+-------+
| AA    | XX    |
+-------+-------+
| BB    | MM    |
+-------+-------+
| CC    | ZZ    |
+-------+-------+
|       | PP    |
+-------+-------+
|       | CC    |
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Have you checked this answer? All 3 solutions returns the exact result you  have requested

Answer (score 2):

The problem as I see it is:

- Fill any holes in Col_2 with one of each of the values from
  OLD_TABLE_B, when you've run out of holes then add new rows.
- Exactly the same technique should to fill Col_3 from OLD_TABLE_C, as so on.  Ideally the initial Col_1 from OLD_TABLE_A should also be able to use the technique although it's a simple insert.
- If you end up with an OLD_TABLE_B_PART_2 this should be able to be run against Col_2 later with the same technique.

The solution needs the following parts:

- A `MERGE` statement as you need to do updates otherwise inserts.
- To use a single `MERGE` for each pass to update multiple rows, each row with different values, you need a unique way of identifying the row for the `ON` clause. With no unique column(s) / primary key you need to use the `ROWID` pseudo-column. This will be very efficient at targeting the row in the table when we get to the `UPDATE` clause as `ROWID` encodes the physical location of the row.
- You need all the rows from OLD_TABLE and as many matching rows from NEW_TABLE you can find with holes, so it's a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. You could do some sort of UNION then aggregate the rows but this would need an often expensive `GROUP BY` and you many need to discard an unknown number of surplus rows from NEW_TABLE.
- To match a (potentially non-unique) row in the OLD_TABLE with a unique hole in the NEW_TABLE, both will need a temporary matching IDs. The `ROWNUM` pseudo-column does this and is cheap.

Given the above, the following statement should work:

```
MERGE INTO NEW_TABLE
USING
  ( SELECT Col_1, ntid
    FROM
      ( SELECT ROWNUM num, Col_1
        FROM OLD_TABLE_B 
        WHERE Col_1 IS NOT NULL
      ) ot 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      ( SELECT ROWNUM num, ROWID ntid
        FROM NEW_TABLE
        WHERE Col_2 IS NULL
      ) nt ON nt.num=ot.num
  ) sel
ON (NEW_TABLE.ROWID=ntid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET Col_2=sel.Col_1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (Col_2) VALUES (sel.Col_1);
```

Check the execution plan before using on big data tables. I've seen the optimiser (in Oracle 12c) use a MERGE or HASH join against the target (NEW_TABLE) for the update rather than a plain USER-ROWID access. In this case the workaround I have used was to force NESTED-LOOP joins i.e. add an optimisation hint to the `MERGE` at the start of the query, so `MERGE /*+ use_nl(NEW_TABLE) */`. You may also need to check how it does `LEFT JOIN` depending on your data.

Answer (score 0):

run below query

```
 INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE (Col_1, Col_2)  
( SELECT Col_1, Col_2
    FROM OLD_TABLE_A 
    WHERE not (Col_1 IS NULL and Col_2 IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that like your way.

### TRY THIS

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE (Col_1,COL_2)  
    SELECT A.Col_1,B.COL_1
    FROM OLD_TABLE_A A FULL OUTER JOIN OLD_TABLE_B B ON 1=1
    AND A.Col_1 IS NOT NULL
    AND B.Col_1 IS NOT NULL;
```